# Proxy doesnt work after I use npm run build

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, proxy, production-environment

I have react app which I want to deploy and upload it to our web server. I use `npm run build`  to do so. However, I have a proxy problem on the live server.

I have an axios post data submit:

```
const onSubmit = (data)  => {
  const info = JSON.stringify(data);
  const webhookUrl = '/jhjk435kj3nkldj5fdgd63/';
  let axiosConfig = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },
  };
  axios.post(webhookUrl, info, axiosConfig),
  .then(axios.spread((data) => {
    console.log('RESPONSE RECEIVED: ', data1)
  }))
};
```

Then I made a `setupProxy.js`:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/jhjk435kj3nkldj5fdgd63/',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'https://h.albato.ru/wh/38/1lfpreg',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

It works fine on my localhost during `npm start`, I get the response and webhook is sent:
[image]

But when I upload it to the live server with `npm run build` proxy doesn't work:
[image]

Comment: A proxy is a part of your server, not of your build. It's not integrated into the app and a frontend app can't contain a proxy. A proxy runs on the backend. `npm start` starts your dev server with proxy. `npm run build` creates the app. You deploy it on your prod server. You need a proxy on your prod server, too.

Comment: @jabaa yeah i thought about it too, but how can i do it?

Comment: Usually I would add an [NGINX Reverse Proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/). But you could probably also implement a proxy into your current webserver. Most webservers for production support it.